# right tracking of image path with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a folder named 'scripts' where my .js files are located and 'images' for photo/pictures.

Whenever I use .click() function to change a `div`'s background-image, I'm struggling with tracking image's path.

here's my folders(hotel is my main folder):

hotel >>> images//rci_hard_rock_hotel_and_casino_punta_cana_0.jpg

hotel >>> scripts/gallery.js

here is my code:

```
$("#gal_choice3").click(function(){
    $("#img_bg").css("background-image","url(../images/rci_hard_rock_hotel_and_casino_punta_cana_0.jpg)");
})
```

I dont know the reason but I always got a `white background` with that `div` whenever I click the button with `id = gal_choice3`

Comment: Maybe you see only part of your image which comprises white color? Try to add also background-size. Or you just have wrong path to your image, cause jquery shoud work fine, there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike with CSS file placed in, for example, /hotel/css/main.css, where you would write path to your route such as `url(../images/rci...jpg)`, jQuery sets the `background-image` property directly in the inline-style of your `div`.

So, my guess is that your coude should be

```
url(./images/rci_hard_rock_hotel_and_casino_punta_cana_0.jpg)
```

Referencing to an image with **./**, instead of **../**, tells the browser to look for it in the current path.

If, however, your folder structure is somehow different, and this doesn't work, try just

```
url(images/rci_hard_rock_hotel_and_casino_punta_cana_0.jpg)
```